# Count number of elements in list prior to occurrence of specific element

Tags: python, list, text, count, element

Assume we have a list of words stored in a list like this:

```
list_of_words = ["this", "is", "a", "text","for", "demonstration"]
```

Furthermore, i have a list of selected words:

```
selected_words = ["hello", "text", "demonstration"]
```

I would like to count the number of words (elements if you like) that occur in list_of_words prior to the words in selected_words that match a word in list_of_words.

I.e. the first word in selected_word that match is "text" and there are 3 words prior to that word in list_of_words. The second word that match is "demonstration" which has 5 words prior to it. So the output should be [3, 5].

What would be the most efficient way to calculate this? I can't seem to find anyone else who have asked this question in python.

Comment: with `[3, 5]` you cannot be sure where the 3 and the 5 come from. Are you sure that this is your ideal output? Something like `[None, 3, 5]` would be much better imo.

Comment: Any attempt / code you have tried so far?

Comment: `[list_of_words.index(word) for word in selected_words if word in list_of_words]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and a conditional [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[i for i, word in enumerate(list_of_words) if word in selected_words]
# [3, 5]
```

If the involved lists are very large you should consider converting `selected_words` into a `set` beforehand to improve the contains-check:

```
selected_words = set(selected_words)
[i for i, word in enumerate(list_of_words) if word in selected_words]
# [3, 5]
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much!. A great input also from Ev.Kounis above: Is there a way to return a NONE if the word does not have a match. So the output would be [NONE, 3, 5] instead.

Comment: @JonathanMarin What if one of the word occurs twice, do you want only the first occurrence?

Comment: It is perfectly fine if words occur twice :-)

Comment: @JonathanMarin But what would you want your output to be like then? :) have the numbers for both occurrences or just the first?

Comment: From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html): `list.index(x): Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.`

Comment: Furthermore, is it possible to add startswith() to the list comprehension, so it finds words that starts with words from selected_words. I've tried something like 
    [i for i, word in enumerate(list_of_words) if word.startswith(selected_words)] , but it doesnt work

Comment: Try: `[i for i, word in enumerate(list_of_words) if any(word.startswith(w) for w in selected_words)]` ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! I think i need to refresh my list comprehensions haha ;-)